# Python List comprehension missing info

Tags: python, list

I am trying to implement the following code into a list comprehension:

```
def incrementValues(m): 
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for ii in range(len(m[i])):
            if m[i][ii] % 2 == 0:
               m[i][ii] //=2 
    return m

m = [[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]]

print(incrementValues(m))
```

So far I have :

```
[[m for m in range(len(m))] for n in range(len(m))]
```

but I cannot work out where this info goes:

```
if m[i][ii] % 2 == 0:
    m[i][ii] //=2
```

If someone could steer me in the right direction, that would be great! (Also, feel free to advise if my original code could be written in a better way)

Thanks :)

Comment: This is a bad candidate for list comprehension, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't create a list, so it probably shouldn't be a list comprehension, which is for creating lists.

Now, in general it is bad for a function to mutate it's inputs. So indeed, you *could create a new list* instead of modifying your list, and you could do that with a list comprehension:

```
[[x//2 if x % 2 == 0 else x for x in sub] for sub in m]
```

but this is doing something different than your code. It is important to understand that.

Note, if you must modify the list, then you should do it this way:

```
def increment_values(m): # stick to python naming conventions
    for sub in m:
        for i, val in enumerate(sub):
            if val % 2 == 0:
               sub[i] //= 2 
    return m
```

Of course, you can also use slice-assignment with a list-comprehension, although, this would make your code less space efficient (which *is* one nice aspect of modifying the list in-place):

```
def increment_values(m): # stick to python naming conventions
    m[:] = [[x//2 if x % 2 == 0 else x for x in sub] for sub in m]
    return m
```

But I would prefer the for-loop version if you are going to do this at all (and I would prefer a version that doesn't mutate the list to begin with...)

Comment: thanks for the explanation! i knew i was missing something minute

Comment: @10216753 In general the rule of thumb is readability, list comprehensions are brilliant when in used short and simple cases but the more complex the structure is the less readable the code gets. For your case I'd stick with the explicit loops and use some more descriptive names.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding list comprehension is

```
m = [[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]]
res = [[item//2 if item%2==0 else item for item in items] for items in m]
```